# Is the subcategory of strict morphisms abelian?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $A$ be an additive category with kernels and cokernels. A morphism $f$ is called strict if the natural morphism from the coimage to the image is an isomorphism.
In *Schneiders: Quasi-abelian categories and sheaves* one finds a proof that the composition of strict morphisms is strict, so the strict morphisms form a subcategory, which we denote by $A_{\mathrm{st}}$.

Is $A_{\mathrm{st}}$ abelian? Where can I find a proof or counterexample?

Comment: No, all morphisms are strict in that sense in the category of groups, which is not Abelian. Not all monomorphisms are the kernel of their cokernel, there are not biproducts, etc.

Comment: @FernandoMuro : the category of groups is not additive

Comment: Ooops, I missed that requirement.

Comment: Jochen Wengenroth has pointed out an "abstract counterexample" but it may be worth noting a more "pedestrian" counterexample based on the fact that Schneiders's QACS monograph explicitly mentions that Ban is an examble of a quasi-abelian category, and in Ban it is well known that following an isometric embedding (=strict mono) with a quotient map (=strict epi) you can get something which does not have closed range (hence not strict)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not believe that the composition of strict morphisms is strict, proposition 1.1.7 of Schneider's *Quasi-Abelian Categories and Sheaves* claims this only for strict epimorphisms as well as for strict monomorphisms.

I think that rather the opposite of the OP's claim is true:

> If all compostions of strict morphisms in an additive category with kernels and cokernels are again strict, then the category is abelian.

To prove this we write an arbitrary morphism $f:X\to Y$ as a composition of a strict epimorphism and a strict monomorphism $$f=\pi_Y\circ [id_X,f]: X\to X\times Y\to Y.$$